# How to parse xml data with attributes in Android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I have an xml data like below:

```
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="madonna"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="madonna like a prayer"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
```

I used Dom parser but it is not working, how can I parse this.

```
public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
      * @param elem element
      */
     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             Log.e("in element","element");
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 Log.e("in child","child nodes");
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                       Log.e("in for","for loop");
                     child = elem.getFirstChild();
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         Log.e("in if condition","if cond");
                         return elem.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }
}
```

Comment: You are writing debug messages to the log. What output are you getting? What is the value of elem when you enter getElementvalue? The for loop in this method also looks suspect - 'child' is the loop variable but you also set it in the body of the loop.

Comment: I have xml data which I mentioned above, I  did not understand how to get the (<suggestion data="madonna"/>) data value from the node mentioned